# Capistrano deployment error in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am getting this error on doing cap production deploy in my rails application
my net-ssh version is 5.0.2
can anyone please help me how i can fix this.
My server is Puma

```
#<Thread:0x00007fe400cfb5e8@/Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    26: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    25: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
    24: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
    23: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:64:in `capture'
    21: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `create_command_and_execute'
    20: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `tap'
    19: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
    18: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `execute_command'
    17: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:176:in `with_ssh'
    16: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
    15: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.17.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
    14: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:246:in `start'
    13: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:71:in `authenticate'
    12: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:71:in `each'
    11: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:85:in `block in authenticate'
    10: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'
     9: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:119:in `each_identity'
     8: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:119:in `each'
     7: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:122:in `block in each_identity'
     6: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:20:in `block in authenticate'
     5: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:62:in `authenticate_with'
     4: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:142:in `sign'
     3: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:44:in `load_private_key'
     2: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:53:in `load_data_private_key'
     1: from /Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:113:in `classify_key'
/Users/synup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/net-ssh-5.0.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/ed25519_loader.rb:21:in `raiseUnlessLoaded': OpenSSH keys only supported if ED25519 is available (NotImplementedError)
net-ssh requires the following gems for ed25519 support:
 * ed25519 (>= 1.2, < 2.0)
 * bcrypt_pbkdf (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
cap aborted!
NotImplementedError: OpenSSH keys only supported if ED25519 is available
net-ssh requires the following gems for ed25519 support:
 * ed25519 (>= 1.2, < 2.0)
 * bcrypt_pbkdf (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
See https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/565 for more information
Gem::LoadError : "ed25519 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile."
```

Comment: first check `cap deploy:check` and fix that errors

Comment: which system do you use mac or linux ?

Comment: i am using mac but my server is ubuntu

Comment: you are firing this command from your local mac terminal. right?

Comment: yes i am firing it from my local mac machine

Comment: did you run `ssh-add [yourkey]` command in your system?

Comment: The error states the missing gems, see @Aarón Castro's answer below

Answer (score 58):

For me just execute on terminal

```
ssh-add
```

And this worked.

Comment: This worked perfectly on my MacBook Pro Big Sur. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me on MacBook Pro Monterey 12.4

Comment: Awesome solution on MacBook Pro Ventrua

Answer (score 12):

On Mac OS at least, you'll get this error if you don't ssh-add [yourkey] after system startup.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer. More detail at https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/478#issuecomment-275113659

Answer (score 7):

My working solution:

Gemfile

```
  gem 'net-ssh', '>= 6.0.2'
  gem 'ed25519', '>= 1.2', '< 2.0'
  gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf', '>= 1.0', '< 2.0'
```

Answer (score 6):

Although you *can* get around this error by adding the gems suggested by the other answers, you don't necessarily *need* to do it this way.

An alternative is to follow the advice given in the Known Issues for Puppet's Bolt tool, in particular [this one](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/bolt_known_issues.html#ssh-keys-generated-with-ssh-keygen-from-openssh-78-fail).

Just in case that link disappears, the solution is to generate your SSH keys in the PEM format rather than OpenSSH. You can do this by adding an extra option to your `ssh-keygen` command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

I've been able to successfully use this technique to avoid adding the extra gems.

Comment: Great!!! Nice solution

Answer (score 3):

This solved the same issue with me

```
ssh-agent -s  && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

Add those gems to your Gemfile,

```
gem 'rbnacl', '< 5.0', :require => false                                                                                                                                                                
gem 'rbnacl-libsodium', :require => false                                                                                                                                                               
gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf', '< 2.0', :require => false
```

and then run `bundle install` and try again.

Comment: Thanx  @Daniel , after adding I am getting error : : expected 64-byte String, got 3 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)

Comment: @pujagarg What's is the version of net-ssh? If version is lower than 5.1.0 then try to run `ssh-add`  in your terminal or run `bundle update net-ssh`.

Comment: Thanx @Daniel , my net-ssh version was 5.0.2 so i did ```ssh-add``` and it worked even after not adding those gems.

Comment: @pujagarg Update net-ssh to 5.1 above, please.

Answer (score 2):

```
gem install ed25519 bcrypt_pbkdf
```

For new keys generated with the ed25519 algorithm, this fixes it

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Macbook M2 and while I tried every alternative suggested in the other answers, I couldn't fix it. The error persisted and changed to a slightly different one: now the problem was incompatible architecture for `bcrypt_pbkdf`:

```bash
The deploy has failed with an error: OpenSSH keys only supported if ED25519 is available
net-ssh requires the following gems for ed25519 support:
 * ed25519 (>= 1.2, < 2.0)
 * bcrypt_pbkdf (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
See https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/565 for more information
LoadError : "dlopen(/Users/*/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bcrypt_pbkdf-1.1.0/lib/bcrypt_pbkdf_ext.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/*/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bcrypt_pbkdf-1.1.0/lib/bcrypt_pbkdf_ext.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/*/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bcrypt_pbkdf-1.1.0/lib/bcrypt_pbkdf_ext.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/*/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bcrypt_pbkdf-1.1.0/lib/bcrypt_pbkdf_ext.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Users/brunocruz/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bcrypt_pbkdf-1.1.0/lib/bcrypt_pbkdf_ext.bundle"
```

I solved it by converting the **new OpenSSH private key** to the **old PEM format**:

```
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now Capistrano can SSH into my server.

Comment: Perfect, the same issue solved on MacBook m3, using this command line

Answer (score 0):

In a multi user developement server, without root permission, this solved:

```bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating `net-ssh` worked for me:

```
bundle update net-ssh
```